# Ecto Changeset add functionality for warnings

Tags: functional-programming, elixir, phoenix-framework, ecto, extending

I created a fork of `ecto` repository to extend `Ecto.Changeset` module with the ability to add warnings to the changeset. I wanted to have an  `add_warnings/4` function which adds a warning to the changeset as a simple list of warnings with this structure `warnings: [{atom, {String.t, Keyword.t}}]`, similar to `errors`. The difference between the behavior of `warnings` and `errors` is that when an error occurs the data are not persisted, but when a warning occurs the data are persisted.

`Ecto.Changeset` struct extended with keys `warnings` and `warningless?`:

```
defstruct valid?: false, warningless?: false, data: nil, params: nil, changes: %{}, repo: nil,
        errors: [], warnings: [], validations: [], required: [], prepare: [],
        constraints: [], filters: %{}, action: nil, types: nil,
        empty_values: @empty_values
```

Ecto functions for casting, changing, processing params, etc. adjusted. Function `add_warnings/4` added:

```
@spec add_warning(t, atom, String.t, Keyword.t) :: t
def add_warning(%{warnings: warnings} = changeset, key, message, keys \\ []) when is_binary(message) do
  %{changeset | warnings: [{key, {message, keys}}|warnings], warningless?: false}
end
```

The result is that I receive `changeset` with expected keys:

```
#Ecto.Changeset<action: nil, changes: %{}, data: #Company.Booking<>, errors: [],
valid?: true, warnings: [], warningless?: true>
```

When I make a change with error and warning I receive:

```
#Ecto.Changeset<action: nil,
changes: %{pickup_address: #Ecto.Changeset<action: :update,
changes: %{street_name: nil}, data: #Company.Address<>,
errors: [street_name: {"can't be blank", [validation: :required]}],
valid?: false,
warnings: [phone_number: {"This phone number is not common in Netherlands",
  []}], warningless?: false>}, data: #Company.Booking<>, errors: [],
valid?: false, warnings: [], warningless?: true>
```

So, everything is as expected, as far as warnings are concerned. Then, when I make a change with a warning but without an error, I receive:

```
#Ecto.Changeset<action: nil,
changes: %{pickup_address: #Ecto.Changeset<action: :update,
changes: %{street_name: "sss"}, data: #Company.Address<>, errors: [],
valid?: true,
warnings: [phone_number: {"This phone number is not common in Netherlands",
  []}], warningless?: false>}, data: #Company.Booking<>, errors: [],
valid?: true, warnings: [], warningless?: true>
```

Everything is as expected. When I don't make any changes to the form I still should receive a warning for phone number, but I receive:

```
#Ecto.Changeset<action: nil, changes: %{}, data: #Company.Booking<>,    errors: [],
valid?: true, warnings: [], warningless?: true>
```

I got a changeset without any warnings as there is no `changes` key in changeset because the data didn't change.

The question is as follows, how to implement warnings functionality to always have warnings in the changeset, even if no change was made?

Comment: You are not showing any changeset function. Presumably what you will want to do is use [`Ecto.Changeset.get_field/3`](https://hexdocs.pm/ecto/Ecto.Changeset.html#get_field/3) instead of [`Ecto.Changeset.get_change/3`](https://hexdocs.pm/ecto/Ecto.Changeset.html#get_change/3) when adding a warning. Though, what is the purpose of this? If you will want to persist the data on warning, you will lose the changeset and not be able to show the user a message.

Answer (score 1):

You should consider to prefill the warnings at the very beginning of the each `changeset` function you would create - since you can't use `plug` there you can come up to write a macro that will handle this logic for you, `__using__` is advised, so it would be quite easy to distinguish your logic from Ecto's default logic.

Your validation shouldn't add warnings to warnings list, but you have to implement it another way around - if the field is fine, you would remove already existing warnings from this list. That way you would be sure that your changeset is fine when it's `warningless`, because it removed all the warnings from this list and it would works perfectly for empty changes in changeset.